# htaccess remove parameter in query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

for some reason our CMS had added after every article `?language=en`. 
We had it fixed but now I need to 301 redirect all links to `/subcategory/%artical%` without the `?language=en`.

I want to redirect:

```
/subcategory/%artical%?language=en
```

to:

```
/subcategory/%artical%
```

I tried this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^www/%1?language=ru ^/www/%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^language=en    [NC]
RewriteRule .*       /$0        [NC,L,R=301]
```

In first line it check that query string contains language=en and then redirect to same url, but without  query string